# Non-word character not being detected after a backslash

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string:

```
hum = "\\w*h(u|v|\\|_\\||\\/)(m|\\/\\\\\\/\\\\)\\w*"
```

which is dumped into the following regex:

```
"I like to hu/\\/\\ every day.".gsub /#{hum}/i, 'sing'
=> "I like to sing every day."
```

It works. But then I do this:

```
"I like to hu/\\/\\ every day.".gsub /#{hum}\b/i, 'sing'
=> "I like to hu/\\/\\ every day."
```

All I did was add a `\b` (non-word character) after `#{hum}`. And there *is* a non-word character there in the string. What's the problem?

Comment: Your regex don't work for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` matches a word boundary. That is a zero-width position where there is a word character on one side and a non-word character on the other side.

Before you add that to the end of the regex, the match is `hu/\\/\\`, and the following character is . When you add `\b` to the regex, you are trying to match `\b` at between `\\` and , which is not a word boundary, so it does not match.

Comment: Of course! Is there a way to force the left side of that \b to act as  a word? Or some other, better solution that would have the same effect?